# Fatal error in launcher: unable to create process - scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using anaconda prompt for installing scrapy. I used the command 
`Conda install -C conda-forge scrapy`
The scrapy is installed by this but if I use any scrapy commands I am getting error,

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using "d:\bld\scrapy_157236038837\_h_env\python.exe" (D:\anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy.exe)
```

I am using `python 3.6.5` version. 
If I look into the path that the fatal error is mentioning there is no python file for scrapy just an application file. How could I clear this error

I checked environment variable and it is fine.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing?